# Please help with identifying this uniform, taken in Turkey 1940s

Tags: world-war-two, military, identification

My Greek uncle worked in the American Embassy in Turkey and this picture I believe was taken in the embassy, circa 1940s - he was about 20+ then.  I have researched epaulettes, uniforms of the Turkish army, but no joy.  It would greatly help to know the identification of this uniform.  My uncle is to the left of uniformed man. Thank you for any help you can give.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

A provisional answer.  A [web page](https://gmic.co.uk/topic/56028-officer-rank-insignia-used-in-the-turkish-army-1909-2012/)  shows several stages of Turkish Army rank insignia history; the fifth illustration, for 1933-1947, with caption

> With the Decree dated 23 May 1933, the shapes of the ranks have been kept but they were applied to the shoulder straps. Also another rank was established Orgeneral (General – now 4 star). Only Maresal insignia (Field Marshal) was kept on the collar. (Picture 18)

shows  the shoulder straps  of a
Tümgeneral (=2 star general, major general), which look to me to be the same as those on your picture.

Comment: Excellent info kimchi lover thank you.  I have enlarged the epaulette section on my photo and the 'blob' next to the star doesn't look like a star, but I can't tell what it is.  This may be the nearest I get to a solution and it does make sense within the context of when and where it was taken.